# How to test UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, xctest

I'm testing a function that presents a UIAlertController, but the test keeps failing. This is what the function looks like:

```swift
func presentBuyingErrorDialogue() {
  let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Warning",
    message: "Error purchasing item, please retry this action. If that doesn't help, try restarting or reinstalling the app.",
    preferredStyle: .alert
  )
  let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
  alert.addAction(okButton)
  self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Since this function is in a class called ShopViewController, I'm assuming that the correct way to test this would be to call the function `shopViewController.presentBuyingErrorDiaologue()` then use `XCTAssertTrue(shopViewController.presentedViewController is UIAlertController)`. However, the assert statement fails when I run the test. What would be the correct way to test that the UIAlertController is the presented view?

Comment: inside your test, try to `print(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)`, what does it say?

Comment: This is what I get when I print: Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7f866985c400>)

Comment: does my answer below help you out ?

Comment: Yes thank you so much for your help so far! But I had to change self.present to UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present, is there a way that I can test the UIController without changing self.present?

Comment: Yes sure, since I don't have your code, I included `presentBuyingErrorDialogue` directly inside the test. In your test case you should make sure your `ShopViewController` is visible and then, from the unit test (eg `testPresentBuyingErrorDialogue`) call the proper `presentBuyingErrorDialogue` with the `XCTestExpectation` mechanism.

Comment: Is this for a unit test, or a UI test?

Comment: @JonReid a unit test

Answer (score 7):

You should wait that `UIAlertController` is fully presented before testing its visibility, so you might try to change your test following this way:

```
import XCTest

class UIAlertControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    func presentBuyingErrorDialogue() {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Error purchasing item, please retry this action. If that doesn't help, try restarting or reinstalling the app.", preferredStyle: .alert)
      let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
      alert.addAction(okButton)
      UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func testPresentBuyingErrorDialogue() {
      self.presentBuyingErrorDialogue()
      let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "testExample")
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        XCTAssertTrue(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is UIAlertController)
        expectation.fulfill()
      })
      wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1.5)
   }
}
```

You may change `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` with your `ShopViewController`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Add [ViewControllerPresentationSpy](https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy) to your test target
2. `import ViewControllerPresentationSpy`
3. Instantiate an AlertVerifier before your test calls `shopViewController.presentBuyingErrorDialogue()`

Then call its `verify` method:

```
alertVerifier.verify(
    title: "Warning",
    message: "Error purchasing item, please retry this action. If that doesn't help, try restarting or reinstalling the app.",
    animated: true,
    presentingViewController: shopViewController,
    actions: [
        .default("OK"),
    ]
)
```

This checks:

- That one alert was presented, with animation.
- That the presenting view controller was the `shopViewController`.
- The alert title.
- The alert message.
- That the preferred style was `.alert` (by default)
- The titles and styles of each action.

In addition to capturing values, AlertVerifier lets you easily execute the action for an alert button:

```
func test_alertOKButton() throws {
    shopViewController.presentBuyingErrorDiaologue()

    try alertVerifier.executeAction(forButton: "OK")

    // Test the results here
}
```

The tests don't require any waiting for expectations, so they are super-fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `completion` parameter of the `present` method to get a callback when the alert is presented, and thus find out whether the alert is shown. (Note that this approach is more about asserting *the correct action was performed*, not *the correct view controller type was shown*).

For this to work, you'll have to add a `completion` parameter to your `presentBuyingErrorDialogue` method, but you can give it a default value of `nil` so that it won't bother you in your non-test code. (Of course you can also use it in you app code when it makes sense, e.g. to start a background animation when the alert appears).

Here's the modified code for the view controller:

```
class ShopViewController: UIViewController {
  func presentBuyingErrorDialogue(completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: completion)
  }
}
```

This is what a simple test might look like (disregarding any cleanup of the `rootViewController`):

```
class ShopViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
  func testErrorAlert() {
    let vc = ShopViewController()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
    let exp = expectation(description: "shows alert")
    vc.presentBuyingErrorDialogue {
      exp.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
  }
}
```

In the app code, you still can use the method as before, without having to provide that callback block:

```
let vc = ShopViewController()
vc.presentBuyingErrorDialogue()
```